# Makefiles: can 'canned recipes' have parameters?

Tags: makefile, dependencies, build-process, gnu-make

My question concerns GNU's make.

If you have a sequence of commands that are useful as a recipe for several targets, a [canned recipe](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Canned-Recipes) comes in handy. I might look like this:

```
define run-foo
# Here comes a
# sequence of commands that are
# executed line by line
endef
```

Now you can use the canned recipe like this:

```
file1: input1:
    $(run-foo)

$(pattern) : sub/% : %.inp
    $(run-foo)
```

and so on. I wonder if it is possible to define canned recipes (or something similar) that take parameters, so that I could execute them like this:

```
file2: input2
    $(run-foo) specific-parameter2 "additional"

file3: input3
    $(run-foo) another-parameter3 "text"
```

Is this possible? Any hints welcome :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You do this by:

- Using parameters `$1`,`$2`... etc in your `define`-ed macro
- Invoking the macro via `$(call ...)`

e.g:

```
define recipe
echo $1
endef

all: t1 t2

t1:
    $(call recipe,"One")

t2:
    $(call recipe,"Two")
```

Comment: The Automatic Variables are valid, so your canned recipe could expand stiff like `${opts-$@}`. Naturally, you will have defined `opts-t1` and `opts-t2` before hand.

Comment: Quotes aren't necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

Nearly 8 years. Okay, Necromancer mode on.
Despite answer by Mike Kinghan mitigates an issue, there's a solution for exact thing being asked.

Almost no black magic takes precedence here.

Simple example for an idea to be clear; just prints out all args:

```makefile
define myrecipe-args
dummy() { printf 'arg: %s\n' "$$@"; }; dummy
endef

mytarget:
    $(myrecipe-args) foo bar baz
```

Complex example, prints out automatic variables as well as args:

```makefile
define myrecipe-full
_() { \
printf '$$@ (target): %s\n' $@; \
printf '$$< (first prereq): %s\n' $<; \
printf '$$^ (all prereqs):'; printf ' %s' $^; echo; \
printf '$$| (order-only prereqs):'; printf ' %s' $|; echo; \
printf 'argv[]: %s\n' "$$@"; \
}; _
endef

mytarget : pa pb | oa ob
        $(myrecipe-full) groovy defaulty targetty
        @echo finally made $@!

pa pb oa ob:
        @echo dummy: $@
```

As you can see it's just cheating on shell functions.
The downside, however, is a requirement for recipe to be one-liner.